# Can I use properties to determine the class of an object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, properties, subclass

I have a custom UITableViewCell created in IB. 
[image]

All my cells will have this general layout. However,in some cells, the two white views will be classA and in other cells the two white views will be classB. (Both subclasses of UIView). I tried to assign the specific subclass of the two views using properties.

I set the two views as properties of the cell

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *leftView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *rightView;
```

And in my view controller where I make the table view, I tried creating an object of type subclassA and assigning it as leftView, so that leftView will be of type subclassA. In other cells, I would create an object of subclass B and set it to leftview, so that in those cells, left view would be of subclass b.

```
//equationTextField is a subclass of UIView
EquationTextField *textField = [[EquationTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; // arbitrary frame
cell.leftView = textField;
```

This code doesn't work, however. Is there a better way to assign the specific class of my views?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is - are you not happy defining your left view and right view as UIView?

Comment: I have two subclasses of UIViews, subclassA and subclassB. In some of the cells of the table, the two views need to be subclassA. In other cells, the views need to be subclass B. Since I made the views in IB, I need a reference to them in code, so I made a property of type UIView since both subclasses can be assigned to that property. I need a way to declare whether I want the left view to be subclass A or subclass B

Comment: It's no problem (unless I am misunderstanding your question). Do the setup in your cellForRow method and use whichever class you need to use depending on the index path.

Comment: I am using one subclass of UITableViewCell for all the cells. I made a general cell, since all my cells are made of the same components, just different subclasses. I'm still not sure if I'm explaining this well enough. I'll try adding a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is fine, but you may want to investigate having two different cell types (with your custom views already embedded) to improve performance - each could have a different reuse identifier which you would choose depending on the index path. Creating views every time in cellForRowAtIndexPath is never a good idea.

You could even derive both types from the same cell, just use the different reuse identifier and add in the correct subclasses only when first creating the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if cell.leftView is your EquationTextField if needed:

```
if([cell.leftView isKindOfClass:[EquationTextField class]]) {
    NSLog(@"View is EquationTextField");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"View is not EquationTextField");
}
```

Comment: p.s. you may have to cast your object instance:

cell.leftView = (UIView *)textField;